# Deserializing JSON and access to elements

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have the following code :

```
dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{ 'Name': 'Jon Smith', 'Address': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'Age': 42 }");
var name = stuff.Name;
MessageBox.Show(name); // print Jon Smith
```

The problem is that I don't know how to access to "Address". So I would like to print "A" then "B" then "C" inside a foreach loop.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: the same way you've accessed `Name` : `var address = stuff.Address;`

Comment: This is not  a correct formatted JSON string.

Comment: @LopDev I suppose that's just a mistyped example

Comment: I suppose this person did not even try to look at the code before posting it to SO, did not even try anything before posting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same approach with `Name` property, then iterate the `Address` value, since it's an array

```cs
var address = stuff.Address;
foreach (var item in address)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: thanks it works well with console.WriteLine() but not with Messagebox.show(). So I updated the code to Messagebox.Show(item.ToString());

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution which will help you also in a lot of Projects.

```
{
  "Name": "Jon Smith",
  "Address": 
  [
    "A",
    "B",
    "C"
  ],
  "Age": "42"
}
```

You have to create a class for your items.

```
public class JSONClass
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string[] Address { get; set; }
   public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

Then you have to make a List that will keep your items:

```
public class ItemsList
{
   public List<JSONClass> JsonItems { get; set;}  
}
```

And then you can simple retrieve your Items.

```
ItemsList itemsList = new ItemsList();

itemsList.JsonItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ItemsList>("yourAPIResponse").JsonItems ;
```